# Multisite network media uploads displaying partially

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, alias, multisite

I have a subdomain multisite installation multisite.domain.com with different sites located multisite.domain.com/sitename etc.

Media uploads are working properly on the main site located multisite.domain.com (files directing to uploads folder) but not on the sub-sites (directing to /files/ not /uploads/).

Images are also displaying correctly on one subsite (multisite.domain.com/livesite) that has been taken live to the domain with an alias www.livesite.com (with uploads directing to livesite.com/files/2019/03/img.jpg etc) which is odd since the same directory is not working on other subsites not live yet.

My htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My Wp-config multisite configurations:

```
define('SUNRISE', true);

/* Multisite */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'multisite.domain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Using Sunrise plugin to create aliases for sites. Tried different solutions as written here for htacess: codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration but didn't work as expected.

Any advise would be appreciated since online sources do not have any new information regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently fixed by using filter in functions.php but doesn't seem to be a final solution:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'same_upload_dir' );
function same_upload_dir( array $uploads ) {
    $baseurl = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/sites/' . get_current_blog_id();
    $basedir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/sites/'. get_current_blog_id();
    $subdir = $uploads['subdir'];

    return array(
        'path'    => $basedir . $subdir,
        'url'     => $baseurl . $subdir,
        'subdir'  => $subdir,
        'basedir' => $basedir,
        'baseurl' => $baseurl,
        'error'   => false,
    );
}
```